# How to get segment addresses from executable file and find stack address

Tags: linux, stack, elf, segment

I need to get start and end of segments that I can get from executable file , for instance using `objdump` command (text,data,bss). I need to obtain this info about file which I call from(program should retrieve info about itself). How can I do this. 
Also I have tried to get start and end addresses of stack segment. I have tried just to get the address of the first and last local variables, but this will show only part of full stack. How can I get addresses of full stack ?

I would be grateful for any help. Thx in advance.

Comment: Why do you ask? What for?

Answer (score 1):

`objdump -h executablename` should enable you to get the section details such as text, data, bss. If you want contents of all sections, then you have to use `-s` option. If you want all the information, then you may need to use the `-x` option (This will have the stack info).

The stack frame retrieval depends on the type of architecture.  An option for getting current stack frame info can be by loading via gdb and executing `info frame` . The address at `frame at` shall be the BP(Base pointer) which shall the starting point of current stack frame. The SP shall contain the ending point of the stack frame.
The address at `locals at` shall contain the start address of local variables.

There are few configurations that can be enabled for kernels. Enabling CONFIG_DEBUG_STACK_USAGE is an option to monitor the kernel stack usage. Options such as CONFIG_DEBUG_STACKOVERFLOW can enable to track stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking from the point of view of the program running itself, I would read the `/proc/self/maps` file (or `/proc/self/smaps`). See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). Reading these pseudo-files is quick (no disk IO involved) but you need to read them sequentially (like with [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s) and to close them "quickly" (in other words, don't re-read them without re-[open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)-ing them).

If you want static information contained in some [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable file (see [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html)) use the [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) & [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) command or some ELF reading library like [`libelf`](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html)

Notice that notion of stack segment is becoming fuzzy with recent kernels, libcs, and multi-threaded applications. See also GCC [split stacks](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/SplitStacks) ability.

Also, most Linux systems are enabling [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR), so stack addresses will vary from one process to another one running the same program.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get start and end of segments that I can get from executable file , for instance using size command (text,data,bss).

The `.text`, `.data` and `.bss` are *sections*, not *segments*. Sections may not be present in the file *at all*, but segments must be (only segments are required at runtime).

> How can I do this.

Study `/usr/include/elf.h`, and many [resources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) available on the web. Each `ELF` file begins with an `Elf{32,64}_Ehdr`, which contains `.e_phoff` and `.e_phnum`. Using these members, you can find and decode the segment table. You can use `.e_shoff` and `.e_shnum` to similarly find the section table (if it is present).

> Also I have tried to get start and end addresses of stack segment

You can't: stack start is not contained in the binary, but is dynamically determined by the kernel at process start time. Further, the *end* of stack is a dynamic property of the running program, and depends on what the program is doing, as well as `ulimit` settings.